# Can anyone break down this sentence into more modern terms?

Tags: meaning, grammar

A sentence from [this letter from Paul Morphy to Fiske confuses me.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150722050734/http://www.edochess.ca/batgirl/Morphy_to_Fiske_Feb4.html)

> It is, to be sure, a most exhilarating sport, but it is only a sport; **and it is not to be wondered at that such as have been** passionately addicted to the charming pastime should one day ask themselves whether sober reason does not advise its utter dereliction.

I understand the rest of the letter, but that bolded part completely melted my brain, particularly the bit between 'such as' and 'have been'. I feel like there's a missing noun there.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, jozen. "Such" refers to those who have been passionately addicted.  This is not bad English, but is a bit old fashioned. It might be re-written:  "and it is not to be wondered that those who have been".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using "such" as a pronoun.

"Such as have been" would appear in more modern text as "people who have been", or "some of those who have been".

Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Ahhhh that explains it.

Comment: another important point is the pause in speech to be made between 'at' and 'that', which makes it clear that 'that' is not a pronoun here, but a conjunction, don't you think?